# How to read complete data from the device using Netty?

Tags: java, gps, nio, netty

Am developing one java application using netty .In this application it will read data from the device and put it into database .But here the problem is once the device send half data it will read and again the device is sending half data . In threads Thread.sleep() method is there to wait for complete data . In Netty am using Non Blocking Ios(NIO). Please tell me how to wait NIOs to read complete data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement your own FrameDecoder which makes sure that the ChannelBuffer will only get based to your business handler once it is complete.

See [1].

[1] https://netty.io/3.9/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FrameDecoder.html

Comment: But here what ever device is sending data that one only make it frame . In my case device is sending broken format data ..

Comment: not necessarily. I also have same issue. device sends data in broken frames and it is working for me. For e.g. the LengthBasedFrameDecoder will wait till the whole data from device has arrived before sending it to next decoder in line. I suggest that you go through the framedecoder examples thoroughly and you will get a solution.

Comment: Hi @Norman, the link you shared is broken. Could you please fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ReplayingDecoder, which will read until data is complete.
[Here you can take a look for example.](http://pastebin.com/spcdqEXg)